# NavigationUI shows back (up) button on Home Destination

Tags: java, android, navigation, android-architecture-navigation, appbar

I am trying to implement `NavigationUI` with Action Bar. I cannot get rid of the back button on my startDestination.

I tried `getActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);` and `getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(false);` however `getActionBar()` returns `null`. I am new to Android programming and I couldn't find a solution. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    NavController navController;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.my_nav_host_fragment);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this,  navController);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        navController.navigateUp();
        return super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }
}
```

Main Activity Layout:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/my_nav_host_fragment"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:defaultNavHost="true"
    app:navGraph="@navigation/app_navigation" />
```

`NavGraph` with the `startDestination`:

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/app_navigation.xml"
    app:startDestination="@id/mainFragment">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/mainFragment"
        android:name="com.tarpinyan.navigationui_test.MainFragment"
        android:label="MainFragment" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_mainFragment_to_timerFragment"
            app:destination="@id/timerFragment" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_mainFragment_to_settingFragment"
            app:destination="@id/settingFragment" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_mainFragment_to_addFragment"
            app:destination="@id/addFragment" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/settingFragment"
        android:name="com.tarpinyan.navigationui_test.SettingFragment"
        android:label="SettingFragment" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/addFragment"
        android:name="com.tarpinyan.navigationui_test.AddFragment"
        android:label="AddFragment" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/timerFragment"
        android:name="com.tarpinyan.navigationui_test.TimerFragment"
        android:label="TimerFragment" />
</navigation>
```

Main Fragment:

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {

    @Nullable
    @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull @NotNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        
        return view;
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(@NonNull @NotNull Menu menu, @NonNull @NotNull MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull @NotNull MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.menu_settings) {
            NavHostFragment.findNavController(this).navigate(R.id.action_mainFragment_to_settingFragment);
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

[Main Fragment with the back button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rn0LP.png)

Comment: Are you sure that your fragment layout does not contain a toolbar with a back button?

Comment: Yes, the Main Activity's layout consists of A Relative Layout and a Fragment (Nav Host), the Main Fragments layout consists of a TextView only. As a last resort, I can try to go with a drawer maybe to hide the problem (not sure if it work) but I really want to found out what's happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the UP button from the first fragment, you need to use the 3-arg version of [`setupActionBarWithNavController()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/ui/NavigationUI#setupActionBarWithNavController(androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity,androidx.navigation.NavController,androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration)) method that takes a `AppBarConfiguration` in which you can specify fragments that you want to remove the UP button from.

```
AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
            R.id.mainFragment) // Remove Up button from mainFragment 
            .build();

setupActionBarWithNavController(this,  navController, appBarConfiguration);
```

**Update:**

> the result is the same, I implemented the 3 arg version but still Main Fragment appears with the up button

Sounds like you explicitly enabled showing the UP button the the main fragment. You need to make sure that [`setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar#setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(boolean)) is not enabled in your mainFragment.

Or you can explicitly disable it by:

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                         @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ((AppCompatActivity)requireActivity()).getSupportActionBar()
                       .setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false); // Hide the UP button

    // ....
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply and edit but the result is the same, I implemented the 3 arg version but still Main Fragment appears with the up button

Comment: @Aras Please check updated answer, also provide us with the code of mainFragment

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but still it did not work however now what happens is when the app first runs, Main Fragment appears with the back button, after navigating to another fragment and returning back, the back button now appears gone.

I also tried to setting different fragments as Home Fragment but the result did not change. I deleted the Nav Graph and done it a second time but still no. 

I updated the code in the post.

Comment: @Aras Do you use the latest dependency of the navigation architecture components?

Comment: Thanks, yes it seems the issue was with the dependencies. I was using Version 2.4.0-alpha03, I reverted to the stable 2.3.5 and now it all works fine. Thank you for both your time and support. This project is a test to try and found out how NavUI works, now I can implement it to my existing projects. Thanks again!